# How to run code when a CancellationToken is cancelled?

Tags: c#, task, cancellation-token

Given a CancellationToken, I want to call a 'cancel' method on an object that represents an asynchronous operation when the CancellationToken is cancelled. Is this possible?

Background: I'm interfacing with an API that represents an async op the following way (more or less):

```
class AsyncOp
{
    void Start(Action callback);//returns 'immediately', while beginning an async op. Callback is called when the operation completes.
    void Cancel();//aborts async operation and calls callback
}
```

I can wrap this in a method `Task DoAsyncOp()` easily enough, but I want to support cancellation, eg `Task DoAsyncOp(CancellationToken cancellationToken)`. In my case, when the CancellationToken is cancelled, call Cancel on the AsyncOp object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can register an `Action` to be invoked when the token is canceled:

```
token.Register(() => { /*...*/ });
```

Comment: Brilliant. Can't believe I didn't notice that method on CancellationToken.

Comment: I worked several weeks with my token until I found it ;-). If you only look for an event you dont see the `Register` method...